# Two function into one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Simple Publish/Unpublish buttons on blade view should update database table column on submit with `0`/`1`.

There are two buttons:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.publish', $book->id), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
    <button class='btn btn-default'>Publish</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.publish', $book->id), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
    <button class='btn btn-danger'>Unpublish</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And two routes

```
Route::post('book/publish/{publish}', 'BookController@publish')->name('book.publish');
Route::post('book/unpublish/{unpublish}', 'BookController@unpublish')->name('book.publish');
```

And the controller

```
public function publish($id){

    $publish = Books::find($id);

    $publish->published = 1;
    $publish->save();        

    return redirect()->route('book');

}

public function unpublish($id){

    $publish = Books::find($id);

    $publish->published = 0;
    $publish->save();        

    return redirect()->route('book');
}
```

Can someone help me to write this into one function. The goal is to show only one button depending of what status has the book. If in database is published then button should show unpublished and opposite way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**

```
public function togglePublish($id)
{
    $publish = Books::find($id);

    if ($publish->published === 1) {
        $publish->published = 0;
    } else {
        $publish->published = 1;
    }

    $publish->save();
    return redirect()->route('book');
}
```

**View**

```
@if($book->published === 1)
    // Show button to unpublish
@else
    // Show button to publish
@endif
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('book/publish/{publish}', 'BookController@togglePublish')->name('book.publish');
```

**Note**

In the controller and view:

```
if ($publish->published === 1)
```

evaluates exactly the same as

```
if ($publish->published)
```

But I think it's clearer to write it explicitly.

Comment: Work's perfectly! Thank's.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to tick as an answer so other people can benefit :)

Comment: I believe my answer is better. Please check

Comment: Let's take it one step at a time. Judging from the question and comment on Alexey's answer, OP is just a beginner and query performance and UX aren't really important just yet. First he has to see what the code does and why it does what it does. Though I agree that your answer is better on pretty much any level ;)

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public function publish($id, $status){
    $publish = Books::find($id);

    $publish->published = $status;
    $publish->save();        

    return redirect()->route('book');
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('book/publish/{publish}/{status}', 'BookController@publish')->name('book.publish');
```

Template:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.publish', $book->id, 1), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
    <button class='btn btn-default'>Publish</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.publish', $book->id, 0), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
    <button class='btn btn-danger'>Unpublish</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change status, you could use ternary operator:

```
$publish->published = $publish->published == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

Or you could try this:

```
$publish->published = !$publish->published;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like this but I'm not that advanced and I've make mistakes and not understanding well ternary yet. @Loek answer is a bit clear for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your view to:

```
@if($book->published === 1)
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.publish', $book->id), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
<button class='btn btn-default'>Publish</button>

@else
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('book.unpublish', $book->id), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
<button class='btn btn-danger'>Unpublish</button>
@endif
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And routes:

```
Route::post('book/publish/{publish}', 'BookController@publish')->name('book.publish');
Route::post('book/unpublish/{unpublish}', 'BookController@unpublish')->name('book.unpublish');
```

And the controller:

```
public function publish($id){

    Books::where('id', $id)->update(['published' => 1]);      
    return redirect()->route('book');

}

public function unpublish($id){

    Books::where('id', $id)->update(['published' => 0]);       
    return redirect()->route('book');
}
```

Why this answer is better than the other ones posted?

1. **Better Query Performance**: This answer invokes just 1 query fired in controller whereas other answers invoke at least 2 queries (one to find the book, one to save)
2. **Better User Experience**: I recommend against the togglePublish method in controller. The reason is that if two different users publish or unpublish the book at the same time, while both will believe the desired action is performed but what would really happen is it would be done and then undone!